# Hashset<T> <- It didn't work in my computer

Tags: c#, hashset

I want to use HashSet in my program.

but I couldn't declare HashSet.

My Computer was installed Microsoft .Net FrameWork 3.5.

and also I declared namespace. (using System.Collections.Generic)

But It didn't work.

How i fix this problem?

i am use visual studio 2005(c#) and Windows 7.

thanks.

Comment: Instead of "It didn't work" it's always helpful to indicate what error message you got.

Comment: +1 for not making any sense and still getting an answer that solved your question.

Answer (score 6):

"i am use visual studio 2005(c#) and Windows 7."

Then you're not using .Net 3.5. You need to specifically reference the System.Core assembly in your project.

Comment: @inchury: glad to help. Feel free to mark this as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The `<T>` means that a hashset is a hashset of a particular type. So for example, you could have a `HashSet<String>` or a `HashSet<Integer>` etc. and you have to declare it as such.

(I'm coming from a Java background but I'm 97% sure it's pretty much the same in C#).

Comment: Hi, MatrixFrog.

Thank you for your answer. But I Know that.

It means I can't declare HashSet<T> type variables.

for example, 

HashSet<string> temp; <- It didn't work.

Comment: Probably not really the problem. He needs to reference a specific assembly, which doesn't happen automatically with that old version of Visual Studio.

Answer (score -2):

Its pretty much the same as java. The only difference is that EVERYTHING inherits from object in c# (even primitives like 'string','int',etc...). Meaning, declare it as:

```
HashSet<string> rather than HashSet<String>
```

Comment: Probably not really the problem. He needs to reference a specific assembly, which doesn't happen automatically with that old version of Visual Studio.

Comment: string and String is the same thing in C#. You might confuse this with Java's boxed types (int vs. Integer).

Comment: Also, string isn't a primitive type.

Comment: I know, I meant to say it just looks like a primitive to someone coming from java. Poor phrasing on my part.